# flutter: command not found when run shell script in Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have created test.sh with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
flutter doctor
```

Everything works fine when I run this script via Terminal:

```
sh test.sh
```

But my script fails when I run it via Jenkins. I get the following error:

```
line 3: flutter: command not found
```

My .bash_profile is:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/Development/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: In pretty much doubt your `~` is the same as Jenkins'

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes. My Jenkins path is: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/ but  how to make flutter work together with Jenkins?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

`~` means `home directory of current user`. So for you it would be i.e. `/home/anivaler` but for Jenkins it most likely be something else. To make it work for anyone get rid of `~` and put the full, absolute path, i.e.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/anivaler/Development/flutter/bin
```

If you are unsure what should be the proper path, just open terminal, `cd` to that directory and do `pwd`:

```
cd ~/Development/flutter/bin
pwd
```

which will show you full path to that directory. Then you just need to edit said `.bashrc` and you should be good.

Comment: Still flutter: command not found. Now my path in .bash_profile is: export PATH="$PATH:/Users/myname/Development/flutter/bin"

Comment: remove `"` (I edited my answer). Also remember you need to close current shell (or or source bashrc by hand) otherwise $PATH is not changed. You can check that with plain `echo $PATH`